# How do i go about on this error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment'

Tags: flask

I am following Corey Schafer tutorials on flask and whenever I run python `run.py`, server starts, but when I click on my register button which is on my app. It's showing the  following error

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment"

I've tried editing the "user" field with no success

My `routes.py` code:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for,flash,redirect
from FLASKBLOG import app, db, bcrypt
from FLASKBLOG.forms import RegistrationForm,LoginForm
from FLASKBLOG.models import user

posts = [
    {
        'author':'Denis muriuki',
        'title':'Blog post 1',
        'content':'Global Macro',
        'date_posted':'July 24,2019'
    }
]



@app.route ("/")
@app.route ("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html",posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html",title='about')

@app.route("/register",methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = user(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("register.html",title='Register',form=form )

@app.route("/login",methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'admin@blog.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            flash('You have been logged in!','success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login unsuccessful.please check username and password','danger')
    return render_template("login.html",title='Login',form=form )





my models.py code
from FLASKBLOG import db

class user(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"user('{self.username}',{self.email}')"


my __init__.py code
rom flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='e95b70cb73d3e650884d944ce06fff25'
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='sqlite:////home/denis/Desktop/flaskblog/site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


from FLASKBLOG import route
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the referenced from `models.py` objects to `routes.py` as the error is showing. Just add:

```py
from app.models import user
```

at the beginning of your `routes.py` and it will be imported. Check also other objects that you use and are not imported.

Please note: if your `models.py` is not located in the `app` folder (starting from your app root folder) you need to change `from app.models import user` to `from <your-path-to-models>.models import user`.

Comment: from FLASKBLOG.models import user

Comment: sure you imported it right? try to rename it to `User` (capital U initial) both in `models.py` , `import` and `routes.py` and see what happens

Comment: after changing it to User

Comment: i got this error 

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta' is not mapped; was a class (FLASKBLOG.models.User) supplied where an instance was required?

Comment: you probably need to update the DB: `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade`. Moreover do you have `from FLASKBLOG import routes, models` in your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Please post your actual routes.py, models.py and __init__.py